# Arranging layout using custom images as buttons

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable

I have images created in my `res/drawable` directory with appropriate `hdpi`, `mdpi`, `xhdpi`, and `xxhdpi` sizings, and I would like to use them instead of regular buttons. I've done that part, but I need some help with the layout and formatting. I'll write my questions first, and then I'll post code and two screenshots below. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

**Details on my device and the images:**

Nexus 5 running Lollipop.

`hdpi` A, B, C, D are 96x96. E is 72x72

`mdpi` A, B, C, D are 64x64. E is 48x48.

`xhdpi` A, B, C, D are 128x128. E is 96x96.

`xxhdpi` A, B, C, D are 192x192. E is 144x144.

**Questions:**

**1) Why has button E on the last row stretched horizontally? Button E is a square with rounded edges, just like all the others, but it is scaled down. Why did it stretch, and how can I fix it?**

**2) How can I arrange the drawables with space between them that will adjust dynamically based on screen size to keep the proportions the same? (See Picture 2 below)**

`fragment_main.xml`: (See Picture 1 below to see how this looks)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentMainTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TableRow
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonA"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/a_selector"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/b_selector"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonC"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/c_selector"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonD"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/d_selector"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/e_selector"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Picture 1, the current layout:**

[image: Current layout]

**Picture 2, the desired layout (but with button E properly shaped):**

[image: Desired layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. hope it helps u...

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentMainTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonA"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonB"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonC"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonD"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**convert ur image like this.**

[image]

Comment: This answer works well as far as sizing E properly and moving it to the bottom of the page. Can you space A, B, C, D out equally? I've tried adding `android:layout_margin="10dp"` to each `Button`, and that spaces them out but puts too much space vertically between the row with A+B and the row with C+D

Comment: add this line to A,B,C and D button `android:layout_margin="5dp"` n try

Comment: @pez you can change android:gravity="center" to android:gravity="bottom" in 2nd TableLayout, this will push button to bottom

Comment: This will work if you add `layout_marginRight,-Bottom,-End = "5dp"` to A, `layout_marginLeft,-Bottom,-Start = "5dp"` to B, `layout_marginRight, -End` = "5dp"` to C, and `layout_marginLeft,-Start = "5dp"` to D.

Comment: better convert ur images with  transparent space with ur requirements

Comment: @MSGadag Is there a way around that? Adding only `layout_margin="5dp"` to ABCD results in [this](http://i.imgur.com/cBTdos4.png). They're closer on the vertical axis than they are on the horizontal one. It might be a good idea to simply add transparent space as you suggested. That would help with compatibility.

Comment: @pez u want to use margin ? check my second image in my ans

Comment: why dont you try like padding your E image
android:paddingLeft="5dip"

Answer (score 4):

For E to be shaped properly, try

```
<TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark"/>

    </TableRow>
```

For spacing between images try using margin property.
Below is the complete code with spacing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragmentMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentMainTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <TableRow
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            android:layout_margin="15dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonB"
            android:layout_margin="15dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonC"
            android:layout_margin="15dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonD"
            android:layout_margin="15dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentMainTableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonE"
            android:layout_margin="15dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Replace the image names

Comment: Your `layout_margin` suggestion works, thank you! However, I need to move button E farther down, nearer to the bottom of the screen. Right now, the other buttons are overlapping part of E. Would it be possible to use something like `Space` dynamically? Also, your suggestion regarding button E didn't have any noticeable effect, unfortunately.

Comment: could you tell me what device you are using to see the output and what is the size of the 5 images?

Comment: @Yogonand.N I will add the information to the main post

Answer (score 0):

Check with Below layout, i didnt changed much but when i tested it working as per your need.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentMainTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonA"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/a_selector" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/b_selector" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonC"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/c_selector" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonD"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/d_selector" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/e_selector" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

>
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/fragmentMainTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/a_selector"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/b_selector"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/c_selector"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/d_selector"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/e_selector"/>

    </TableRow>

   </TableLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```